# Nlog config: Move older log from Archive folder to some other location

Tags: logging, nlog, archive

I have configured the Nlog file to archive the file daily with max limit of 10000000 Byte. Max Archive file count is 200. Once max limit is reached, old file is being deleted from archive folder. I want to keep older logs (for 4-5 month) some where else on network so do not want to delete it after max archive instead want to move it.

```
<target name="file" xsi:type="Iit.AsyncWrapper">
      <target type="File"
            archiveAboveSize="10000000"
            archiveEvery="Day"
            maxArchiveFiles="200"
            archiveNumbering="Rolling"
            archiveFileName = "${logDirectory}/archive/log.{#####}.txt"
            fileName="${logDirectory}/log.txt"
            layout="${longdate}|${level}|${processid}|${threadid}|${message}"
            concurrentWrites="false"
            keepFileOpen="true"
            encoding="iso-8859-2" />
    </target>
```

Once Archive limit is reached, instead of deleting old files, I want to copy the older log file to another location on network.
is there a way to achieve the same in nlog?
How can I implement this?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is only one supported archive folder, and that is the folder you specify in `archiveFileName`.

Comment: Yes I know. And to repeat NLog only supports one archive folder. You can configure `archiveFileName` to point to your network-folder, and NLog will move it there on archive.

Comment: But the problem is after max archive it will delete the older file. I want log.0199.txt in configured path and all other older older file to move that new location so that I can have logs older than years. Please read the problem statement for detail

Comment: See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/3873

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create a batch file instead of configuring nlog. For this create a batch file to copy new files on network. You can also manage those files to be deleted if older than said days.

Comment: Thanks for answer, that I can do but i am looking something in nlog only. As nlog provide configuration to do auto archive and auto cleanup feature so wondering if there is some configuration or way to achieve it via nlog only.

Comment: try enableFileDelete configuration. As per this you can disable deletion https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/File-target